# Replacing a value on a data.frame based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, plyr

This is somewhat a follow-up on a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893023/nas-are-not-allowed-in-subscripted-assignments) where the idea is to replace a given value in data.frame based on multiple conditions.

Here is a simple example that works, with base R:

```
df <- data.frame( var1=c("k",2,NA,6,5,"K","k",1),
              var2=c(4,2,6,0,9,1,3,2),
              var3=c("d","d","d","d","d","d","n","f"))
df

    var1 var2 var3
1    k    4    d
2    2    2    d
3 <NA>    6    d
4    6    0    d
5    5    9    d
6    K    1    d
7    k    3    n
8    1    2    f
```

The objective is to modify the value `var1==k` & `var3==n`by say a factor of 9:

```
df$var2[df$var1=="k" & df$var3=="n"] <- df$var2[df$var1=="k" & df$var3=="n"]/9
```

However, the actual df of interest generates the error message stated in the above question. The answer provided therein, negate NA's with each condition, `df$var1=="k" & !is.na(df$var1)` solves the issue with ample lines of code.

My question: is there a simpler solution using let's say `plyr`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`).  We specify the logical condition in 'i', assign (`:=`) the variable ('var2')  as 'var2/9'.  This would be efficient as it modifies in place.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!is.na(var1) & var1=='k' & var3=='n', var2 := var2/9]
```

Comment: @ akrun: thanks for the tip! Looks like converting `df` to data.table class object had no impact on applying `dplyr`-like operations to it later.