# Combining two variables in r

Tags: r

I think this is a super easy question, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have two variables: `varA` and `varB`.

`varA` has values `'a'` and `NA`, and varB has values `'b'` and `NA`.

I want to combine them into one variable `varC` with value `'a'` where `varA` is `=='a'` and `'b'` where `varB` is `=='b'`.

I have tried this:

```
varC <- varA
varC[varB=='b'] <- varB
```

but I get the error:

> Error in [<-.factor(tmp, varB == "b",  : 
>     NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `NA=="b"` returns `NA`. And `NA`s are not allowed when doing assignments like `varC[NA] <- 1` - I'm guessing you probably need to wrap your test `varB == "b"` like `which(varB=='b')`.

Comment: Relevant discussion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893023/nas-are-not-allowed-in-subscripted-assignments

Comment: `varC[which(varB=='b')] <- varB[which(varB=='b')]`

Comment: Also consider `varA <- c(NA,"a"); varB <- c("b",NA); pmax(varA,varB,na.rm=TRUE)` if there is always clearly only one of either 'a' or 'b' that is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `varB=='b'` will return `NA` when `varB` is `NA`. Use `is.na()` to test for `NA`. Here is an example:

```
a <- c(NA, 'a', NA)
b <- c('b', NA, 'b')

c <- a
c[is.na(c)] <- b[is.na(c)]

c

[1] "b" "a" "b"
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to convert it using as.numeric() first. I think my dataset got converted into r format kind of funkily, factors-wise. Thanks for the simple solution.