# Convert 24 hour time from Character type to 24 hour time and subtract two times

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two columns stored as character data that represent 24-hour time.

```
Wakeup <- c("0700", "0515", "0815")

Bedtime <- c("2400", "2230", "0100")
```

I would like to subtract these times and get the desired column below (as numeric).

```
Hours_slept <- c(7, 6.75, 7.25)
```

I would like to use the tidyverse.

Answer (score 4):

There's a few interesting things to think through here, such as how to convert to a time object (if that's what you're aiming for) and how to work out time distance without a date (we can tell that 2230 is day before wakeup and 0100 is same day, but R doesn't).

If you want to stick to very tidyversey ways of doing things, then you can make it a tibble and `mutate` using `lubridate` functions:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

Wakeup <- c("0700", "0515", "0815")

Bedtime <- c("2400", "2230", "0100")

tibble(Bedtime, Wakeup) %>%
  mutate(
    # First change makes each a time, formatting time string by inserting space
    across(.fns = ~ str_replace(.x, "(?=\\d{2}$)", " ") %>% hm()),
    # Then time difference
    time_diff = Wakeup - Bedtime,
    # Some are negative - a quick fix may be just to add 24h
    time_diff = if_else(time_diff < 0, hours(24) + time_diff, time_diff),
    # Then convert to decimal number of hours
    time_diff = as.numeric(time_diff) / (60 * 60)
  )

#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Bedtime    Wakeup    time_diff
#>   <Period>   <Period>      <dbl>
#> 1 24H 0M 0S  7H 0M 0S       7   
#> 2 22H 30M 0S 5H 15M 0S      6.75
#> 3 1H 0M 0S   8H 15M 0S      7.25
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I thought "24:00" would be a problem, coercing to `NA` or sth equivalent, but actually it doesn't -- nice work!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a base R implementation.  Like Andy mentioned, there is an assumption that the `Bedtime` must be before `Wakeup`, and by no more than a day:

```
Wakeup <- c("0700", "0515", "0815")
Bedtime <- c("2400", "2230", "0100")

Wakeup <- as.POSIXct(Wakeup, format='%H%M')
Bedtime <- as.POSIXct(Bedtime, format='%H%M')
Bedtime[Bedtime > Wakeup] <- Bedtime[Bedtime > Wakeup] - as.difftime(1, units='days')
Hours_slept <- as.numeric(difftime(Wakeup, Bedtime, units='hours'))
# [1] 7.00 6.75 7.25
```

The input hours are converted into datetimes, (which by default will take the current date).  Subtract one day from any times where the bed time is greater than the corresponding wakeup.  Then subtract the datetimes with `difftime` and get the data in numeric hours.

---

OP brought up the issue of missing values in the comments.  My initial solution fails with `Error in NextMethod(.Generic) :    NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments`.  [Following here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26893023/13386979), one fix is to check for NAs when subscripting:

```
Wakeup <- c("0700", NA, "0815")
Bedtime <- c("2400", "2230", "0100")
IsNA <- is.na(Wakeup) | is.na(Bedtime) # FALSE  TRUE FALSE

Wakeup <- as.POSIXct(Wakeup, format='%H%M')
Bedtime <- as.POSIXct(Bedtime, format='%H%M')

# subscripting accounts for NAs now
Bedtime[Bedtime > Wakeup & ! IsNA] <- Bedtime[Bedtime > Wakeup & ! IsNA] - as.difftime(1, units='days')
Hours_slept <- as.numeric(difftime(Wakeup, Bedtime, units='hours'))
# 7.00   NA 7.25
```

But this also led me to another solution, which I maybe prefer in general.  Calculate the difference in the automatically generated date times, and add 24 (hours) to any negative values.  This seems to work with `NA`s without any additional fuss (it uses `ifelse` and avoids the subscripting with `NA`):

```
Wakeup <- c("0700", "0515", "0815")
Bedtime <- c("2400", "2230", NA)

Wakeup <- as.POSIXct(Wakeup, format='%H%M')
Bedtime <- as.POSIXct(Bedtime, format='%H%M')
Hours_slept <- as.numeric(difftime(Wakeup, Bedtime, units='hours'))
Hours_slept <- ifelse(Hours_slept < 0, Hours_slept + 24, Hours_slept)
# 7.00 6.75   NA
```

Comment: Thank you, how do I handle NAs here: ```Bedtime[Bedtime > Wakeup] <- Bedtime[Bedtime > Wakeup] - as.difftime(1, units='days')```

Comment: @Cat I believe right now if any element of `Bedtime` or `Wakeup` is `NA`, the corresponding entry in `Hours_slept` will also be `NA`.  Do you expect something else?

Comment: This is the error that I get: ```Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments```

Comment: @Cat sorry, I see that now!  Think I needed to clear my environment.  See my edits, I added some alternatives for handling NAs

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! The last solution you provided works exactly as I need it to.