# Philips & Horton models for water infiltration

Tags: r, nlme

I'm trying to run soil-water infiltration data in Rstudio for an experiment set up as an RCBD with treatments and a blocking effect. My variables include the depth and time measured in the field (i.e. multiple values for each variable per treatment), as well as the dry and wet volumentric water content (this is one value per teratment). I do not have the hydraulic conductivity or sorptivity.

I've been trying out different types of code but can't get any to work but there's not a lot of examples out there. Ideally I want to run a Philips non-linear (e.g. ssPhilips) model or a Horton (e.g. ssHorton) non-linear model on my data. If this is not possible I'd like to just run a generic non-linear model on my data. An extract of the first two treatments:

```
Block,Treatment,Time,CI,mDry,mWet
Block1,Control 1,0,0,0.0299,0.564
Block1,Control 1,48,10,0.0299,0.564
Block1,Control 1,217,20,0.0299,0.564
Block1,Control 1,848,30,0.0299,0.564
Block1,Control 1,2288,40,0.0299,0.564
Block1,Control 1,3911,50,0.0299,0.564
Block1,Control 1,5855,60,0.0299,0.564
Block1,Control 1,8624,70,0.0299,0.564
Block1,Control 1,11472,80,0.0299,0.564
Block1,Control 1,13581,90,0.0299,0.564
Block1,Control 1,16724,100,0.0299,0.564
Block1,Biochar25kgPha,0,0,0.027355623,0.299869622
Block1,Biochar25kgPha,90,10,0.027355623,0.299869622
Block1,Biochar25kgPha,200,20,0.027355623,0.299869622
Block1,Biochar25kgPha,341,30,0.027355623,0.299869622
Block1,Biochar25kgPha,604,40,0.027355623,0.299869622
Block1,Biochar25kgPha,1028,50,0.027355623,0.299869622
Block1,Biochar25kgPha,1486,60,0.027355623,0.299869622
Block1,Biochar25kgPha,2168,70,0.027355623,0.299869622
Block1,Biochar25kgPha,3030,80,0.027355623,0.299869622
Block1,Biochar25kgPha,4363,90,0.027355623,0.299869622
Block1,Biochar25kgPha,5461,100,0.027355623,0.299869622
```

For an attempt at a general non-linear model, I have the following:

```
InfilMod <- nlme::gnls(CI ~ (Kf * (t ^ alpha)) / alpha,
your textdata = Infil,
weights = nlme::varIdent(form = ~1 | Treatment),
method = "ML",
control = nlme::glsControl(maxIter = 1000),
correlation = nlme::corAR1(form = ~Time | Block/Treatment),
na.action = na.exclude)
```

This gives:

```
Error in diff[pp != 0] <- pp[pp != 0] * ssize : NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

There are no empty cells or missing data in my data frame, although there are zero values (all of my measurements started at t=0).

How should I fix the code to run with my variables? And if anyone has any other suggestions for code to run Philips or Horton models, or anything else for infiltration data to get infiltration rates I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: The function name is `gnls()`.

Comment: Thanks. And apologies, I tried updating it after I realised this mistake. I'm now getting the error:
```
Error in diff[pp != 0] <- pp[pp != 0] * ssize :  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

I have no empty cells or missing data in my dataframe, although there are zeros. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: You'll need to create a different question, and to provide code and data to run the code on in order to reproduce the issue, either by copying the output of `dput()` or by using a publicly available dataset.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new at this. What do you mean by creating a different question? As in I need to change my model? Or redo the stack question and add the data in another format?

Comment: As in, ask a new question on the SO platform. As per [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26893230/5221626) it is possible that you are doing something with your model that is creating NAs. My guess from the error is the inclusions of 0s in your data, since it specifically references `pp != 0`.

Comment: Thanks Phill! I've updated this question, but will look into the null value issue now to see if that will correct it.